# How to assign results of an http function within array.map() in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, es6-promise, array.prototype.map

I've read MANY articles, but I'm totally a newbie to this whole async thing and am having a very hard time wrapping my brain around how it all works. I want to map the filtered array of objects, and inside that, I'd like to return the result of a function (an amount) and set that as the value of pmtdue.  I tried this a bunch of ways, but always get zoneawarepromise or observable when it's logged, or a ton of errors.  This is probably the closest I've gotten, but it's still not right.

```
async today(day = null, status = null) {
    this.logger.log(`show today's ${status} appts ${day}`);
    // filter master list for today
    const filtered = [...this.apptList].filter(appt => {
      if (!status) {
        return (
          appt.scheduled >= this.helperService.dayStart(day) &&
          appt.scheduled <= this.helperService.dayEnd(day) &&
          appt.status.status !== 'Checked Out' &&
          appt.status.status !== 'Scheduled'
        );
      } else {
        return (
          appt.scheduled >= this.helperService.dayStart(day) &&
          appt.scheduled <= this.helperService.dayEnd(day) &&
          appt.status.status === status
        );
      }
    });
    // calculate due amount and map it to pmtdue field
    const dueappts = await this.getTotalDue(filtered).then(
      res => {
        // console.log(res);
        this.ApptModels = res;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
    // send the data to ng2-smart-table
    console.log(`filtered ApptModels`, this.ApptModels);
}
```

This is the function that does the mapping and has the functions I want to work
     // a.pmtduedate returns the correct value as there is no http call
     // a.pmtdue returns a zoneawarepromise but I don't know how to get the VALUE

```
 getTotalDue(appts: Array<any>): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.all(
      appts.map(async (a: any) => {
        a.pmtduedate = await this.helperService.getDueDate(a);
        a.pmtdue = await this.dataService.sendTotalDue(a);
        console.log(a.pmtdue); // logs undefined
        return a;
      })
    );
  }
```

My data service function (I know sometimes code matters that I think is insignificant):

```
 async sendTotalDue(appt) {
this.logger.log(`fetch amount ${appt.patientID.nickname} owes`);
return await this.http.post(`${SERVER_URL}/sendtotaldue`, appt);
}
```

And finally, the backend function(minus details on data).  It logs the correct amount on the backend, I just can't get it to display on the frontend:

```
module.exports.sendTotalDue = (req, res) => {
  const appt = req.body;
  // callback function that handles returning data
  function done(err, results) {
    const totaldue = parseInt(results, 10);
    console.log(`API sendTotalDue CALLBACK done...totaldue: ${totaldue}`);
    if (err) {
      console.log('ERROR getting total due: callback error', err);
      res.sendStatus(500).json(err); // server error; it'd be good to be more specific if possible
    } else {
      // end the request, send totaldue to frontend
      console.log(`SUCCESS send totaldue to frontend ${totaldue}`);
      res.status(200).json(totaldue);
    }
  }
  // run first function
  console.log(`1.  getAmtDue:`);
  this.getAmtDue(appt, done);
};

module.exports.getAmtDue(appt, callback) {
... function finds past visits, past payment and due totals
}
module.exports.getCurrentDue(appt, pastdueamt, callback) {
... function finds current visits and payments.  calculates current due and adds the past due
callback(null, totaldue);
}
```

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?  Feel free to dumb it down for me, cause that's how I feel at this point.

EDITED TO FIX ERRORS like missing await and return.  It is now to the point where I can see the value returned in the data service, but I get undefined in the map function section.
[image: This image shows what is returned from the map function (Observable)]

Comment: Seems like you only forgot the `await` keyword in `a.pmtdue = await this.dataService.sendTotalDue(a);` - `sendTotalDue` returns a promise.

Comment: Also I guess inside `sendTotalDue` you want to do `return this.http.post(`${SERVER_URL}/sendtotaldue`, appt);` so that a promise is returned that resolves with the response from the backend.

Comment: I fixed those things, but still didn't get the value returned.  Sorry, I noticed those errors after I posted.  I DID do an update that allows me to get the value returned and logged in the data service, but it logs as undefined in the map function.  I'll edit the post to show that.

Comment: Well there's still no `return` in the `sendTotalDue` function. The one you put in the `then` callback doesn't help. And don't use `then` when you work with `async`/`await`.

Comment: I put return in there and it still didn't return the value.  I keep getting either Observable returned or zoneaware promise.  I just don't get it!  :'(

Comment: Can you update you code to show how you added the `return`, as well as mark the point where you are getting only a promise?

Comment: @Bergi yes.  I updated it. Inside the map function, I'm running a a.pmtdue = await this.dataService.sendTotalDue(a);  This is logging as an Observable, unless I add .toPromise() (then it logs as a zoneaware promise.

Answer (score 0):

Ooooh!!!  I GOT IT!  I still don't totally understand WHY it works, but I changed the data service as follows:

```
async sendTotalDue(appt): Promise<any> {
    this.logger.log(`fetch amount ${appt.patientID.nickname} owes`);
    try {
      const result = await this.http
        .post(`${SERVER_URL}/sendtotaldue`, appt)
        .toPromise();
      return result as any[];
    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Changing my service to the above finally got my values to appear exactly where I wanted them in the data table!  :)

I found this article, which helped figure out how to work with Observable
[Angular Tutorial with Async and Await](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170127-Angular2TutorialWithAsyncAndAwait.html)